# Single column from Multiple columns from join in SQL

Tags: sql, join, teradata

I have a table output like this, which is a result of multiple table joins.

```
+---------+------+--------+------+
|   Id    | V1   | V2     | V3   | 
+---------+------+--------+------+
|    1    | x1   | null   |  null|
|    2    | x2   | null   |  null|
|    3    | null | x3     |  null|
|    4    | null | x4     |  null|
|    5    | null | null   |  x9  |
+---------+------+--------+------+
```

I am trying to get a table like this.

```
+---------+------+
|   Id    | V    |  
+---------+------+
|    1    | x1   | 
|    2    | x2   | 
|    3    | x3   |
|    4    | x4   |
|    5    | x5   |
+---------+------+
```

This is what i am doing currently doing. Not sure how to make the three columns combine to a single column.

```
select a.identifier, a.v1, b.v2, c.v3,
from table a
full join table b on a.identifier = b.identifier
full join table c on a.identifier = c.identifier
where a.v REGEXP 'some condition'
```

Comment: there are only v1, v2 and v3? or more column?

Comment: more columns. For simplicity i have added just these.

Comment: Is it a fixed number of columns? Also, the SQL you provided is confusing me. Is it one table? What if a row has both v1 and v2 non-null values? Also, are you applying the REGEXP condition on the combined column `v`?

Comment: What's wrong with `SELECT a.identifier, COALESCE(a.v1, b.v2, c.v3)`?

Comment: @Nick post it as an answer :)

Comment: @Aziz I think I must be missing something... I'll wait for OP to confirm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one value per row -- or if you just want the first one-- then use `coalesce()`:

```
select id, coalesce(v1, v2, v3) as v
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do have a look at - [COALESCE() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_coalesce.asp), it returns the first non-null value in a list.